# TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data when plotting array with imshow()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

For the following code

```
# Numerical operation
SN_map_final = (new_SN_map - mean_SN) / sigma_SN  

# Plot figure
fig12 = plt.figure(12)
fig_SN_final = plt.imshow(SN_map_final, interpolation='nearest')
plt.colorbar()

fig12 = plt.savefig(outname12)
```

with `new_SN_map` being a 1D array and `mean_SN` and `sigma_SN` being constants, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Valentin\Desktop\Stage M2\density_map_simple.py", line 546, in <module>
    fig_SN_final = plt.imshow(SN_map_final, interpolation='nearest')
  File "c:\users\valentin\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3022, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\valentin\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1812, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\valentin\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4947, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "c:\users\valentin\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\user\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 453, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

What is the source of this error? I thought my numerical operations were allowed.

Comment: Read the error message and provide missing information. The error is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Can you print the variable SN_map_final?

Comment: Also, fix your title. It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @MSeifert I obtain : (63865L,) that's to say is a 1D array ?

Comment: @Mad Physicist Hum my question is about a numerical operation on my array right ? Sorry if I don't see where the title is not good :/

Comment: Your problem is "Invalid dimensions for image data", raised by your call to `imshow`. The array operation works fine.

Comment: @Reti43 So the minus vote is necessary ?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I only improved the presentation of the post. I think as it stands now it's a fine question, but the downvoter is probably long gone.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There is a (somewhat) related question on StackOverflow:

- [Showing an image with pylab.imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008045/showing-an-image-with-pylab-imshow)

Here the problem was that an array of shape (nx,ny,1) is still considered a 3D array, and must be `squeeze`d or sliced into a 2D array.

More generally, the reason for the Exception

> TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

is shown here: [`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) needs a 2D array, or a 3D array with the third dimension being of shape 3 or 4!

You can easily check this with (these checks are done by `imshow`, this function is only meant to give a more specific message in case it's not a valid input):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

def valid_imshow_data(data):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    if data.ndim == 2:
        return True
    elif data.ndim == 3:
        if 3 <= data.shape[2] <= 4:
            return True
        else:
            print('The "data" has 3 dimensions but the last dimension '
                  'must have a length of 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA), not "{}".'
                  ''.format(data.shape[2]))
            return False
    else:
        print('To visualize an image the data must be 2 dimensional or '
              '3 dimensional, not "{}".'
              ''.format(data.ndim))
        return False
```

In your case:

```
>>> new_SN_map = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> valid_imshow_data(new_SN_map)
To visualize an image the data must be 2 dimensional or 3 dimensional, not "1".
False
```

The `np.asarray` is what is done internally by `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow` so it's generally best you do it too. If you have a numpy array it's obsolete but if not (for example a `list`) it's necessary.

---

In your specific case you got a 1D array, so you need to add a dimension with [`np.expand_dims()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a = np.expand_dims(a, axis=0)  # or axis=1
plt.imshow(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

or just use something that accepts 1D arrays like `plot`:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.plot(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]