# matplotlib can't plot single channel or greyscale image pixels

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, keras

I was working with an image problem and suddenly hit a stone somewhere when I had to check for the image plotting before network training and I foud something odd. I thought my `ImageDataGenerator` was not working properly but it was `matplotlib`. I as working with grayscale images.

so if you use

```
data4 = np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(137,236,4))
data3 = np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(137,236,3))
data1 = np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(137,236,1))

pyplot.imshow(data4)
pyplot.imshow(data3)
```

it plots the random noise very well but when you do,

`pyplot.imshow(data1)`it throws an error `Invalid shape (137, 236, 1) for image data`

but again for

```
data = np.random.randint(low=0,high=255,size=(137,236))
pyplot.imshow(data)
```

it plotted very well. Why is that happening? what causes the `pyplot` to throw an error when using the  c=1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data when plotting array with imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431496/typeerror-invalid-dimensions-for-image-data-when-plotting-array-with-imshow)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matplotlib can plot single-channel images. From the documentation of [imshow](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), the input X is:

> X : array-like or PIL image The image data. Supported array shapes
>   are:
>
> - (M, N): an image with scalar data. The data is visualized using a    colormap.
> - (M, N, 3): an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int).
> - (M, N, 4): an image with RGBA values (0-1 float or 0-255 int), i.e.    including transparency.
>
> The first two dimensions (M, N) define the rows and columns of the
>   image.
>
> Out-of-range RGB(A) values are clipped.

So, your `data3` is assumed to be an RGB image, `data4` an RGBA image, `data` a single channel image, whereas the `data1` has incorrect dimensions for the `imshow()` (use `data1.squeeze(axis=2)` instead).

Comment: Thank you very much. This problem took a couple of days of my life.