# Plot 1-D matrix vertically with imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a 1-D matrix (vector) vertically with imshow.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431496/typeerror-invalid-dimensions-for-image-data-when-plotting-array-with-imshow) post helped me plot the vector horizontally with imshow, using "expand_dims".

But most tips to plot it vertically (transpose vector before plotting; use imshow's "origin" keyword) do not work, probably because it is 1-D. Does anyone have any suggestions for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same expand dim with axis parameter as 1

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) 
>>> a.shape
(4,)
>>> plt.imshow(np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)); plt.show()
```

works as expected.