# index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is my code:

```
def VisualizeResults(index):
    img = X_valid[index]
    img = img[np.newaxis, ...]
    pred_y = unet.predict(img)
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_y[0], axis=-1)
    pred_mask = pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]
    fig, arr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 15))
    arr[0].imshow(X_valid[index])
    arr[0].set_title('Processed Image')
    arr[1].imshow(y_valid[index,:,:,0])
    arr[1].set_title('Actual Masked Image ')
    arr[2].imshow(pred_mask[:,:,0])
    arr[2].set_title('Predicted Masked Image ')

# Add any index to contrast the predicted mask with actual mask
index = 10
VisualizeResults(index)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-2652988c2408> in <module>
      1 # Add any index to contrast the predicted mask with actual mask
      2 index = 10
----> 3 VisualizeResults(index)

<ipython-input-78-30f9f35d62a8> in VisualizeResults(index)
      1 def VisualizeResults(index):
----> 2     img = X_valid[index]
      3     img = img[np.newaxis, ...]
      4     pred_y = unet.predict(img)
      5     pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_y[0], axis=-1)

IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9
```

I have grayscale input images both original and masked (128 * 128 * 1), and how to visualize the original, masked, and predicted masked images.
Also if I want to overlay the predicted masked and masked on the original image and colour it with some colour.

Comment: python start numerating with 0. that means that if you have a vector with 10 elements you can index it from 0 to 9. Index 10 will be outside of the boundaries of the vector which is what the error is telling you.

Comment: Not wrong, but the size seems to be 9, so 0...8 are valid indices.

Comment: Still I am getting the same error.

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [22], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 # Add any index to contrast the predicted mask with actual mask
      2 index = 9
----> 3 VisualizeResults(index)

Input In [21], in VisualizeResults(index)
      1 def VisualizeResults(index):
----> 2     img = X_valid[index]
      3     img = img[np.newaxis, ...]
      4     pred_y = unet.predict(img)

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

Comment: Please can you `print(X_valid.shape)`? If that one gives you error: `print(len(X_valid))` ?

Comment: size `9` has indexes `0...8` - you can't use `9` or `10`

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431496/typeerror-invalid-dimensions-for-image-data-when-plotting-array-with-imshow

I used this code to see the dimension of X_valid and y_valid

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

def valid_imshow_data(data):
    data = np.asarray(data)
    if data.ndim == 2:
        return True
    elif data.ndim == 3:
        if 3 <= data.shape[2] <= 4:
            return True
        else:
            print('The "data" has 3 dimensions but the last dimension '
                  'must have a length of 3 (RGB) or 4 (RGBA), not "{}".'
                  ''.format(data.shape[2]))
            return False
    else:
        print('To visualize an image the data must be 2 dimensional or '
              '3 dimensional, not "{}".'
              ''.format(data.ndim))
        return False

valid_imshow_data(y_valid)
```

Then I used `np.squeeze()`
Reference: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-squeeze/

Modified the code a little bit to get the result:

```
def VisualizeResults(index):
    img = X_valid[index]
    img = img[np.newaxis, ...]
    pred_y = unet.predict(img)
    pred_mask = tf.argmax(pred_y[0], axis=-1)
    pred_mask = pred_mask[..., tf.newaxis]
    fig, arr = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 15))
    arr[0].imshow(X_valid[index])
    arr[0].set_title('Processed Image')
    arr[1].imshow(y_valid[index])
    arr[1].set_title('Actual Masked Image ')
    arr[2].imshow(pred_mask[:,:,0])
    arr[2].set_title('Predicted Masked Image ')
```

As index 10 was out of scope therefore I added

```
index = 8
VisualizeResults(index)
```

And it solved the problem. Thank you.