# I am getting error with im.show()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to save a gray scale image (256,256,1) and show it in the output.

```
im = data.astype(np.uint8)
print im.shape
im = np.transpose(im, (2,1,0)) 
print im.shape
im.show()
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
(256, 256, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lmdb_reader.py", line 37, in <module>
    plt.imshow(im)
  File "/home/se/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3029, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/se/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1819, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/se/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4922, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "/home/se/anaconda2/envs/caffeenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 453, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing an image with pylab.imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008045/showing-an-image-with-pylab-imshow)

Answer (score 7):

Note that `im.show()` does not exist, but it might just be a typo in the question. 
The real problem is the following:

Matplotlib's `pyplot.imshow` can plot images of dimension `(N,M)` (grayscale) or `(N,M,3)` (rgb color). Your image is `(N,M,1)`; we therefore need to **get rid of the last dimension**.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#create data of shape (256,256,1)
data = np.random.rand(256,256,1)*255
im = data.astype(np.uint8)
print im.shape # prints (256L, 256L, 1L)
# (256,256,1) cannot be plotted, therefore 
# we need to get rid of the last dimension:
im = im[:,:,0]
print im.shape # (256L, 256L)
# now the image can be plotted
plt.imshow(im, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the colormap before calling matplotlib.pyplot.show().
By default the function expects RGB images when you pass a 3D array.

Example:

```
im = np.squeeze(im)
plt.imshow(im,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```