# Correctly reshaping MNIST images through keras

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

If I download the CIFAR 10 Images in Keras via:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()

# Getting shape
x_train.shape
>>> (50000, 32, 32, 3)
```

I can then plot each image by doing:

```
# Plot RGB image
plt.imshow(x_train[0])

#  Plot only one colour-channel e.g. R
plt.imshow(x_train[0][:,:,0])
```

Now I get the MNIST images via Keras by doing:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# getting shape
X_train.shape
>>> (60000, 28, 28)
```

However it doesn't have a depth channel which should be 1 as it's grayscale. If I reshape it using:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0],28,28,1)
```

I can get the Neural Net to work but I can not plot it anymore. What is the correct way to reshape it so that I can still plot things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you reshape the training and testing set, you have to reshape the images back to plot them.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
...
plt.imshow(X_train[num].reshape(28,28))
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that but how would I get it to have the shape (numPics, 28, 28, 1) and still work? Clearly it works if I have (numPics, 32,32, 3). That tells me having the depth layer in the shape is still ok...

Comment: Yes, having the depth layer in the shape is ok.

Comment: So why can't I plot it with the depth layer in the shape? That's my initial problem....

Comment: When plotting a 3D array, it expects RGB or RGBA data so we have to get rid of the extra dimension before plotting. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008045/showing-an-image-with-pylab-imshow)

Answer (score 0):

As of [v3.3](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.4/users/whats_new.html#imshow-now-coerces-3d-arrays-with-depth-1-to-2d) matplotlib's `imshow` now coerces 3d arrays of size MxNx1 into MxN for displaying, so you can plot your reshaped `X_train` without issue.