# Invalid dimension for image data in plt.imshow()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, keras, typeerror, mnist

I am using mnist dataset for training a capsule network in keras background.
After training, I want to display an image from mnist dataset. For loading images, mnist.load_data() is used. The data is stored as (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test).
Now, for visualizing image, my code is as follows:

```
img_path = x_test[1]  
print(img_path.shape)
plt.imshow(img_path)
plt.show()
```

The code gives output as follows:

```
(28, 28, 1)
```

and the error on plt.imshow(img_path) as follows:

```
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

How to show image in png format. Help!

Comment: You should remove the redundant channel dimension. Try `plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img_path))`

Comment: @sdcbr Thank you so much. It works..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing an image with pylab.imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008045/showing-an-image-with-pylab-imshow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.squeeze` for removing dimensions of size 1 from the shape of a tensor.

```
plt.imshow( tf.shape( tf.squeeze(x_train) ) )
```

[Check out TF2.0 example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze)

Answer (score 7):

As per the comment of @sdcbr using np.sqeeze reduces unnecessary dimension. If image is 2 dimensions then imshow function works fine. If image has 3 dimensions then you have to reduce extra 1 dimension. But, for higher dim data you will have to reduce it to 2 dims, so np.sqeeze may be applied multiple times. (Or you may use some other dim reduction functions for higher dim data)

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img_path = x_test[1]  
print(img_path.shape)
if(len(img_path.shape) == 3):
    plt.imshow(np.squeeze(img_path))
elif(len(img_path.shape) == 2):
    plt.imshow(img_path)
else:
    print("Higher dimensional data")
```

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
plt.imshow(test_images[0])
```

> TypeError: Invalid shape (28, 28, 1) for image data

Correction:

```
plt.imshow((tf.squeeze(test_images[0])))
```

[Number 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecCr2.png)

Answer (score 0):

`matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` does not support images of shape `(h, w, 1)`. Just remove the last dimension of the image by reshaping the image to `(h, w)`: `newimage = reshape(img,(h,w))`.